# Redirect to a page after ajax post success

Tags: jquery

I am trying to go to a page after ajax success without any success.This is my code

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: {kwargs : le_selected },
  url: baseurl,
  success: function(data){
     var url = "http://localhost/ye/index.php/enterprise/q_qwargs/"+data;    
$(location).attr('href',url);
  }
    });
```

The code above takes me to the page `http://localhost/ye/index.php/enterprise/q_qwargs` and leaves out the values in the `data`.

here is the `post` and `get` in firebug before redirection

[image]
How can i make this include the data that is being left out?.

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` say?

Comment: You have an extra `+` before one of your semicolon, which I am going to assume is a typo. Did you check whether your data was an empty string?

Comment: alert(data); gives what??

Comment: I can get the post data on itself,its a value `6`.Just before redirecting,it works.The url reads `http://localhost/ye/index.php/enterprise/q_qwargs/6` but after now going to the page,the `6` is gone.

Comment: The server is probably rewriting it then.

Comment: The screenshot shows that it's redirecting correctly. Check your server's rewrite rules.

Comment: I don't even have a .htaccess anywhere in the application i am making.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
location.href='http://localhost/ye/index.php/enterprise/q_qwargs'+data;
```

Comment: That's equivalent to what he wrote (minus the typo).

Comment: window.location.href="http://localhost/ye/index.php/enterprise/q_qwargs"+data; should work fine. but you have to format data to key value pairs like question=5&view=1

Answer (score 0):

change this,

```
var url = "http://localhost/ye/index.php/enterprise/q_qwargs/"+data; 
$(location).attr('href',url);
```

Comment: @Barmar i have included a screenshot in the question.